# Azure service to send SMS and Email notifications

Tags: c#, .net, azure

I have mainly worked in AWS and there is AWS SNS which can send SMS and email notifications. The alternative in Azure appears to be Azure Notification Hub, which cannot do this. Apparently it only sends push notifications.

Is there a service that I could use to implement SMS and Email notifications (including email templates) in Azure?

Comment: You can email from LogicApps with crazy amounts of ease and Communication Services is your best bet for SMS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Azure Communication Services are cloud-based services with REST APIs and client library SDKs available to help you integrate communication into your applications. You can add communication to your applications without being an expert in underlying technologies such as media encoding or telephony.

From: [What is Azure Communication Services?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/overview)

Azure Communication Services provides quite a few options, among which are chat, email and SMS.

There are decent articles on how you can [Send an SMS message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/quickstarts/sms/send) or [Send an email](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/quickstarts/email/send-email).

**EDIT:**

> Azure Logic Apps is a cloud platform where you can create and run automated workflows with little to no code. By using the visual designer and selecting from prebuilt operations, you can quickly build a workflow that integrates and manages your apps, data, services, and systems.

So Logic Apps is not a service to send SMS or email. Logic Apps is a low-code platform that enables you to very easily *call* a service that sends an SMS or an email. And one such service could be Twilio, since ...

> Twilio powers personalized interactions and trusted global communications to connect you with customers.

Of course there are other providers, too, like MessageBird, Spryng, CM.com and more.

Comment: Thank you very much! So I could send both SMS and Emails through Azure Communication Services? Because @Skin mentioned Logic Apps for emails in the comments above

Comment: Like how does Azure Communication Services compare to Logic Apps for emails and Twilio Send Grid?

Answer (score 1):

for sms/emails try Azure Communication Services: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/quickstarts/sms/send?tabs=windows&pivots=platform-azcli

For email notifications only you have also different choices. You can buy "kiosk" from 365 business licence, so you can create account only for this licence in your tenant, send email from code is standard smtp approach. For templating you can use whatever you want, as you can send html message loaded for example from resx file. You can also use service nammed SendGrid from Twilio. I recomend using SendGrid, only if there are really plenty of emails.